# Is “就快下雨了” correct Mandarin?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, cantonese

I've been watching Peppa Pig to improve my Mandarin, but here at [1:59](https://youtu.be/FJXXsNonea0?list=PLlQZ8mzWUstDasSayy8OpqwbXsktDpXeg&t=119), the mama pig says  “就快下雨了”  meaning to say that it will rain soon. However I thought that the phrase "就快" was Cantonese only, and that you generally use something like "很快" in mandarin. Is the above sentence correct Mandarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 就快下雨了 is idiomatic in Mandarin.  The similar variations are: 快要下雨了，快下雨了，就要下雨了，天就快下雨了，天快下雨了，天要下雨了，etc.